# Date variable remains same even after submitting the form

Tags: reactjs, onclick, event-listener, use-state, onsubmit

Trying to set date when clicked onSubmit but it still remains in same state even after setDate.

```
    const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDate(moment(Date.now()).format(format1));
    

    axios
        .post('http://localhost:4000/questions', {
            ques: ques,
            quesBrief: quesBrief,
            hashes: hashes,
            author: author,
            date: date,
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            history.push('/');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
return (
 <div className='mt-4 w-1/2'>
 <button className=' w-40 text-md px-4 ml-2 mt py-3 rounded bg-orange-500 text-white font-bold 
 hover:bg-gray-1100 hover:text-orange-500  lg:mt-0 transition ease-out duration-500'
  onClick={onSubmit}
 >
 Post Question
 </button>
)
```

After clicking onSubmit, I have this object

```
  {ques: 'fjfds', quesBrief: 'sdagd', hashes: '#dsa', author: 'Me2', date: '', …}
  author: "Me2"
  date: ""
  hashes: "#dsa"
  id: "Vv7I1c9"
  ques: "fjfds"
  quesBrief: "sdagd"
```

The date remains blank. However, if I submit the second time, date is set successfully. Can somebody explain this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Setting state is asynchronous in React. The only way to see the new state value would be after the rerender. If you want to use the value immediately, use a variable.

```
const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newDate = moment(Date.now()).format(format1);
    setDate(newDate);
    

    axios
        .post('http://localhost:4000/questions', {
            ques: ques,
            quesBrief: quesBrief,
            hashes: hashes,
            author: author,
            date: newDate,
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            history.push('/');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

Comment: Nah, not working, still shows the same. And I've used react-time ago too. So it says invalid date given to react-time-ago.

Comment: Just saw a mistake in my code. Have fixed it. The variable to use is `newDate`. Please check now

Comment: I got it fixed too. I used an useEffect so that it will set the setDate just after it renders. 
 useEffect(() => {
  setDate(moment(Date.now()).format(format1));
 }, []);
This worked. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. That will work too. Will work only after component mounts.